# Losing scope of variable

Tags: angularjs

So in my angularJS program, I'm trying to retrieve data from the database and I do so successfully but then lose the value of my variable. Why is this and how can I fix this?

```
    function loadLocOptions() {
        locTaskOptionsReq.requestLocTaskOptions(vm.task).then(function (data) {
            if (data == null) {
                vm.locOptions = locTaskOptionsService.getEmptylocTaskOption();
                vm.locOptions.ERPKey = sessionService.getCurrentUser().ERPKey;
                vm.locOptions.LocKey = sessionService.getCurrentUser().LocKey;
            } else {
                vm.locOptions = data;
            }
            vm.locOptionsLoaded = true;
            // Data is here
            console.log(vm.locOptions);
        });
        // Now is null
        console.log(vm.locOptions);
    }
```

i'm trying to then call use my `locOptions` to use my html:

```html
<div ng-repeat="loc in vm.locOptions">...</div>
```

here's my controller that as well:

```
module.component("asaLocOptionsComponent", {
    bindings: { task: '='},
    controllerAs: "vm",
    controller: ["$scope", "$location", "shellPageAdapter", "sessionService", "staticData", "activeData", "ScreenModes", "localizationService", "locationReq", "locTaskOptionsService", "locTaskOptionsReq", asaLocOptionsController],
    transclude: false,
    templateUrl: "/system/SystemManager/app/organization/asaLocOptions.html"
});
```

Comment: Because the call to `locTaskOptionsReq.requestLocTaskOptions` is asynchronous and your `console.log(vm.locOptions);` line is hit before the promise resolves.

Comment: @Lex ah okay, that makes sense. how can I fix that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is my variable unaltered after I modify it inside of a function? - Asynchronous code reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23667086/why-is-my-variable-unaltered-after-i-modify-it-inside-of-a-function-asynchron)

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan, probably not since the OP is using a promise. The promise hasnt resolved yet which fills in the value of vm.locOptionsLoaded. Once the promise resolves, the value will be filled in.

Comment: @Esaith Did you read that question and its answers? It talks about exactly that.

Comment: Yes, you are right. Sorry for skimming it too quickly ><

Comment: You can get rid of the `ng-if` because if the collection you are iterating with `ng-repeat` is empty it won't output anything. Is that not working for you? Show how `vm` is initialized in your controller as well as your `ng-controller` directive from the view/route/whatever.

Comment: @Lex I updated it

Comment: So at the top of your controller you have `var vm = this;`? Also, `vm.locOptions` looks like an object, not an array. If you are trying to loop the key/value pairs of the object in your `ng-repeat` you'll need to use something like `ng-repeat="(key,value) in vm.locOptions"`.

Comment: @Lex i do have that at the top of my controller. and oh okay, how would that work with my ng-switch then?

Comment: You don't have an `ng-switch` in your question. There are lots of examples of looping an object's properties using `(key,value)` in an `ng-repeat`. Try some and then update your question if you still can't figure it out.

Answer (score 3):

What is happening that your service call requestLocTaskOptions is async calls which means it doesn't stop the thread execution. So it will continue and executes

```
console.log(vm.locOptions); // Which is null currently as your callback is not executed yet
```

After the results is retrieved your then callback is executed and vm.locOptions will be set.

So your required code/ business must be included inside the Then Call back or you can create watcher on the vm.locOptions to be executed on value change.

Comment: I've updated my question with my html and since I have an ng-if, shouldn't that work?

Comment: if vm.locOptions is init as [] your ng-if will always give you true, you can use better vm.locOptions.length, after your then callback apply cycle will run which will update your view

Comment: @HanyHabib, what if initialized with a value of 1, then after the promise returns its a difficult value but still length of one? The OP could splice(0) the array if such a circumstance exists.

Comment: Esaith you have valid point but why to Initialize array declaration with value 1? i feel that is not valid scenario in this case.

Comment: @HanyHabib no. but when I console.log the length of vm.locOptions it says undefined

Comment: can you provide the code on plunkr and i will update it for you? because it seems maybe you have other binding issue

Comment: do you have this line of code at the beginning of your controller?  var vm = this;